# How to ng-if another div is visible

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two lists of stuff using ng-repeat. Then I want it to say "empty" if there are no items in a list.

Here's the updated version:

```
     <!-- First List -->
        <div ng-repeat="request in requests" ng-if="request.condition1 == 'something'">
            {{request}}
        </div>
        <div>Empty list</div>

     <!-- Second List (both use requests array but have different conditions-->
        <div ng-repeat="request in requests" ng-if="request.condition22222 == 'something else'">
            {{request}}
        </div>
        <div>Empty list</div>
```

Comment: Is `list` an array or object?

Comment: What is `dd`? What is `list`?

Comment: I just gave it a model named list so that if there are no requests, I'd assume there's no list. List = nothing except my attempt to MacGyver this.

Comment: dd is just like a div. It's a list in bootstrap. I'll edit this to use divs for simplicity.

Comment: After your edited post, for such requirement in the view, I suggest that you pre-filter the array in your controller before you're using it in the view. Unless, there's something that forces you to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('app', [])
  .filter('decorate', function() {    
  return function(input, model) {   
    return input.filter(function(val){      
      return val[model.prop] == model.val;
    });    
  };
}).controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.requests = [{name:'Tom', age:23},{name:'Henry', age:23},{name:'Max', age:33}];    
    $scope.$filter = $filter;
  }]) 
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">

  <div ng-init='items1=$filter("decorate")(requests, {prop:"age", val:23})'>First list(age=23):</div>
  <div ng-repeat='item in items1' ng-if='items1.length > 0' >{{item | json}}</div>
  <div ng-if='items1.length == 0'>Empty</div>

  <br/>  

  <div ng-init='items2=$filter("decorate")(requests, {prop:"name", val:"Sam"})'>Second list(name=Sam):</div>
  <div ng-repeat='item in items2' ng-if='items2'>{{item | json}}</div>
  <div ng-if='items2.length == 0'>Empty</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check against the length of your list and show it conditionally:

```
<div ng-show="!requests.length">List is empty</div>
```

If you're working with an object you can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) although it may not be supported in some older browsers.

Comment: How did you know that list is an `array`?

Comment: I don't, but I've edited to give an option in case it's an object.